# Peewee: How to select data from Postgres where array field is empty?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

Here is a simple Peewee model to work with Postgres

```
import playhouse.postgres_ext as pg


db = pg.PostgresqlDatabase(""" credentials ... """)


class Artist(pg.Model):
   name = pg.TextField()
   albums = pg.ArrayField(pg.TextField, default=[])

   class Meta:
      database = db


db.create_table(Artist)
Artist.create(name='name1', albums=['album11', 'album12'])
Artist.create(name='name2')
```

For selecting artists with no albums the SQL query may be

```
>> SELECT * FROM artist WHERE albums = '{}';

 id | name  | albums 
----+-------+--------
  2 | name2 | {}
```

or for selecting artists with specific name

```
>> SELECT * FROM artist WHERE name = 'name1';

 id | name  |      albums       
----+-------+-------------------
  1 | name1 | {album11,album12}
```

But when I try to achieve it with Peewee I get the following results

```
res = Artist.select().where(Artist.name == 'name1')
assert len(res) == 1 and res[0].name == 'name1'

res = Artist.select().where(Artist.albums == '{}')
assert len(res) == 0
```

The first query takes `'name1'` as query parameter.

The second query takes `playhouse.postgres_ext._Array` object as query parameter.

I've looked at documentation on [Postgres Extensions](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#ArrayField) and did not find anything suitable.

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong and how to select data with empty array field?

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent of `WHERE array_length(albums,1) = 0` in a form suitable to `playhouse.postgres_ext` ?

Comment: Alternatively, how about to a comparison with Python empty array/list: `[]`? That is: `res = Artist.select().where(Artist.albums == [])`

Comment: @joanolo Thanks for suggestion, in my case it will be `WHERE array_length(albums,1) IS NULL`. I've looked at `playhouse.postgres_ext.fn` and did not find any equivalent of `array_length()` there. `Artist.select().where(Artist.albums == [])` does not work either.

Comment: Apparently playhouse isn't good enough to deal with this case, it translates it into `SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name", "t1"."albums" FROM "artist" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."albums" = ())` which is not valid PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop into raw SQL to work around this limitation:

```
res = Artist.select().where(SQL("albums = '{}'"))
print(len(res))
```